# Federated authentication for external sites interfering login inside the cms

Tags: federated-authentication

I am using federated authentication to login/signup to the websites in multi sites architecture.
No issues for the websites but for the cms when I open **cmsurl.com/sitecore** it takes to the website's login page

I have created a patch config that has:

1. pipeline processor,
2. map entries for identityProvidersPerSites,
3. and the designated identity provider for identityProviders.

Wondering what can cause this? may be config  patch order or something?
Any insights or recommendations would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

We have used the following patch for the CM site to force login to Azure when they hit the CM backend and for admin path we force to identity server login.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:security="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/security/">
  <sitecore role:require="ContentManagement">   
    <sites>
    <!-- Force redirect to Azure login page -->
      <site name="shell" set:loginPage="$(loginPath)shell/SitecoreIdentityServer/IdS4-AzureAd" />
    <!-- Force redirect to regular login page -->
      <site name="admin" set:loginPage="$(loginPath)admin/SitecoreIdentityServer" />
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: any way to distinguish in Standalone setting

Comment: This works in standalone too, if you are asking for XP0.

Comment: Hi @Bala I added this ContentManagement or Standalone but still External IdentityProvider intercepts the login for the CMS

Comment: Please use the sitecore\admin\showconfig.aspx and see which one is effective and taking effect.

Answer (score 0):

The question here seems similar to the one you posted here: [Issues with IdentityProvidersProcessor Sitecore Federated Autentication in multisite architecture](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/30798/issues-with-identityprovidersprocessor-sitecore-federated-autentication-in-multi)

Maybe my answer there can also help you: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/31311/3309